# Nginx reverse proxy only accessible from one device

Tags: networking, 18.04, proxy, nginx, transmission

Following [this](https://www.htpcguides.com/secure-nginx-reverse-proxy-with-lets-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/) guide, I've set up Nginx reverse proxy for transmission, but for some reason it's only accessible through my laptop. On my laptop (Windows 10), I can access it with Chrome or Firefox, even in a VM (Ubuntu) I can access it, also even through a VPN.

On my phone and iPad I can't access the webpages. It just says connection failed or connection refused, depends on the device and  browser used.

I set it up exactly like the webpage above, modifying things that I have to according to the guide.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

When I look into the link you have followed I found that on the server name you have bounded your local server IP so either kindly connect with the same network. So that you can access the local domain. Find the screen shoot(https://prnt.sc/qbyypd) for explanation